# Catching an exception when creating a new SoapClient properly

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having a difficult time catching a SoapClient authentication issue.  When my code executes, Laravel declares it's throwing an ErrorException but I can't seem to catch it no matter what code I use.  I'm tagging Laravel in case there's some magic going on somewhere I don't know about because App::error() will trigger on this error still.

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient(
        $this->serviceUrl . $this->clients[$clientName],
        array(
            'login'      => $this->username,
            'password'   => $this->password,
            'exceptions' => true,
        )
    );
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    die('soapfault never fires!');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('exception won\t t');
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    die('error exception also doesn\'t error');
}
```

According to Laravel an ErrorException is being thrown but the above code doesn't catch it.

```
ErrorException

SoapClient::SoapClient(https://control.akamai.com/nmrws/services/RealtimeReports?wsdl) [<a href='soapclient.soapclient'>soapclient.soapclient</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 1):

Add backslash before exception types (e.g. `Exception` becomes `\Exception`).

They belong to global namespace. Your code tries to catch exceptions in currently used namespace which doesn't have to be the same as global.