# How to deal with "Request denied by Throttle server" SOAP responses in Laravel 5

Tags: php, web-services, soap, laravel-5, throttling

I have made a web application that uses SOAP exchanges to get data from a Web API.  This was initially done in a procedural way and I'm now trying to move it into a Laravel framework.  I have a `view` set up to display to the user if the SOAP Response is "Request denied by Throttle server" but I don't know how to check for that particular error.  Here is the Class:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use SoapClient;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class SoapWrapper {

public function soapExchange() {

    // set WSDL for authentication and create new SOAP client
    $auth_url  = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl";

    // set WSDL for search and create new SOAP client
    $search_url = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WokSearch?wsdl";

    // array options are temporary and used to track request & response data
    $auth_client = @new SoapClient($auth_url);

    // array options are temporary and used to track request & response data
    $search_client = @new SoapClient($search_url);

    // run 'authenticate' method and store as variable
    $auth_response = $auth_client->authenticate();

    // call 'setCookie' method on '$search_client' storing SID (Session ID) as the response (value) given from the 'authenticate' method
    // check if an SID has been set, if not it means Throttle server has stopped the query, therefore display error message
    if (isset($auth_response->return)) {
        $search_client->__setCookie('SID',$auth_response->return);
    } else {
        return Redirect::route('throttle');
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that it throws the "Request denied by Throttle server" default Laravel error at `$auth_response = $auth_client->authenticate();` before it gets to the `if` statement that checks if a value (SessionID) has been returned by the SOAP Request.  It didn't do this when it was set up in a procedural way for some reason.

The `if` statement checks if a value has been returned from the `authenticate()` method and if it has, assigns it (SessionID) to the cookie of the search client to authorise searches.  Otherwise it displays a custom error message.

I have tried using `is_soap_fault` but that doesn't catch it because it isn't technically a soap fault.  I've also tried removing the line causing the problem and changing the `if` statement to:

```
if (isset($auth_client->authenticate()->return) {...
```

But that just causes the default Laravel SoapFault page too.  The `return Redirect::route('throttle')` displays a custom error page to the user, saved as `throttle.blade.php`.

Anyone know how I can test for the throttle error?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found answer here: [Catching an exception when creating a new SoapClient properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301984/catching-an-exception-when-creating-a-new-soapclient-properly).

I'll post my amended code anyway just in case it's of any use to anyone else in future:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use SoapClient;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class SoapWrapper {

public function soapExchange() {

    try {
        // set WSDL for authentication and create new SOAP client
        $auth_url = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl";

        // set WSDL for search and create new SOAP client
        $search_url = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WokSearch?wsdl";

        // array options are temporary and used to track request & response data
        $auth_client = @new SoapClient($auth_url);

        // array options are temporary and used to track request & response data
        $search_client = @new SoapClient($search_url);

        // run 'authenticate' method and store as variable
        $auth_response = $auth_client->authenticate();

        // add SID (SessionID) returned from authenticate() to cookie of search client
        $search_client->__setCookie('SID', $auth_response->return);

    } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
        return Redirect::route('throttle');
    }
}
}
```